# How to set default values for enumitem list parameters

Tags: lists, itemize, enumitem

I want to format all my (`enumitem`-based) lists so that they all look like this:

```
\begin{itemize}[labelindent=\parindent,leftmargin=*]
    \item (...)
\end{itemize}
```

However, I'd like to skip the explicit configuration everytime I create a list. Is there a way to set these values as default throughout the document? Would there be issues in nested lists?

Comment: See the \setlist command in the documentation.

Comment: There should not be an issue with nested lists, as long as you define them accordingly (like using `label*`, say, for `enumerate` to use parent-level enumeration).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
\setlist[<list>,<level>]{<settings>}
```

The use of `<list>` and `<level>` is optional. See section **5 Global Settings** of the [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem).